# use nginx as reverse proxy for a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to using docker and nginx together so i apologize in advance for my simple question which I am unable to get an answer to despite going through many resources on youtube.

I created an ubuntu server and ran the following command

```
sudo apt install nginx
```

Now I have a very simple flask application docker image(publicly available on docker hub and not developed by me) and I want to configure my nginx to work as a reverse proxy to my container running the said image.

My code for the reverse proxy in nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://192.168.0.20:8000"
    }
}
```

192.168.0.20 is my server ip and 8000 is the host port over which i am forwarding my docker container like

```
docker container run -p 8000:5000 <image>
```

But when I run http://192.168.0.20/ it opens default nginx index.html whereas I want it to forward to my app container to serve that static file because when i run http://192.168.0.20:8000/ it gives me desired output.

**This might sound like a dumb question but i have been struggling to get a hang of nginx.**

Thanks in advance for the help !!!

Comment: When you want containers to talk to each other, you should add them to the same docker network, and use the service name as the hostname. Trying to connect to you host machines IP is the wrong way to go about it. The easiest way to do this is to run the containers together using `docker-compose`, it will use a default network for all the containers in the stack.

Comment: i dont have nginx as a container but a direct install on ubuntu server with just one image. Also i am not aware of where to setup docker compose.

Comment: How do you put the nginx config into the container? Because it gives you the default welcome page, it looks like it's not picking up your configuration.

Comment: @HansKilian i think i might have missed that step because i can't seem to find a way to get in the container or the location where i can map the config volume

Answer (score 1):

To reach the host from inside the container, you can't use 192.168.0.20, since that address isn't known inside the container. Depending on your host OS, you can use 172.17.0.1 (Linux) or host.docker.internal (Windows). If your OS is Linux, you should change your config to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://172.17.0.1:8000/"
    }
}
```

Rather than installing nginx yourself, you can use the nginx images that are available on docker hub. To get your config file into it, you copy it to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. Create a Dockerfile containing

```
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Build and run it with

```
docker build -t mynginx .
docker run -d -p 80:80 mynginx
```

Now you should be able to go to http://192.168.0.20/ and get a response from the Flask app.